# How to pass Object to ModelAttribute in controller - Spring

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, modelattribute

Is it possible to pass an object (car) to my controller by using a select tag? When i try to use the following code, the car parameter is not recognised and it results is:

> 400-Bad Request

A `car` consists of 2 Strings (Brand, Model)
A `spot` consists of 1 car and 2 Strings (town, streetName)

My jsp page:

```
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="spot" action="${post_url}">        
    <form:select path="car">   
        <form:option value="-" label="--Select car"/>  
        <form:options items="${cars}"/>
    </form:select> 

    <form:input type="text" path="town"/>        
    <form:input type="text" path="streetName"/>            
    <button>Save</button>
</form:form>
```

My controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addSpot", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String save(@ModelAttribute("spot") Spot spot){   
    service.addSpotToService(spot);      
    return "redirect:/spots.htm";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can creta a component to convert the Long id of Car to object car

```
@Component
public class CarEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {

    private @Autowired CarService carService;

    // Converts a Long to a Car
    @Override
    public void setAsText(Long id) {
        Car c = this.carService.findById(id);

        this.setValue(c);
    }

}
```

in your controller add this

```
private @Autowired CarEditor carEditor;

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Car.class, this.carEditor);
    }
```

and then pass the id of car in the select

```
    <form:select path="car">   
        <form:option value="-" label="--Select car"/>  
        <form:options items="${cars}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="model"/>
    </form:select>
```

have a look at the spring documentation  http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html and specifically at the section **The options tag**

> The items attribute is typically populated with a collection or array
>   of item objects. itemValue and itemLabel simply refer to bean
>   properties of those item objects, if specified; otherwise, the item
>   objects themselves will be stringified. Alternatively, you may specify
>   a Map of items, in which case the map keys are interpreted as option
>   values and the map values correspond to option labels. If itemValue
>   and/or itemLabel happen to be specified as well, the item value
>   property will apply to the map key and the item label property will
>   apply to the map value.

Let me know if this worked for you

Comment: When i implement this, i get a error while loading the jsp that the property 'car' of bean class Car is invalid. Probably because the path in the <form:select> is set to "car"

Comment: Does the class Car has an id?